# How can I "replace" the name of a model's ID with a field from another model?

Tags: python, django

How can I "replace" the name of a model's ID (Memorandum) with the first_name of the other model (User) in a table list in a template?

I use the default user model of django.

Example:
[Picture Template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bRcwn.png)

**From (ID = de) | Date | Detail**

2 | 2/2/2018 | Commentary

TO

**From (ID = de) | Date | Detail**

Jane | 2/2/2018 | Commentary

**view.py**

```
def MemoList(request, usuario):

    instancia = get_object_or_404(Empleado, usuario_id=usuario)

    lista2 = Memorandum.objects.filter(para_id=instancia)


    for usuarios in lista2:
        lista_de_id = usuarios.de_id
        lista_para_id = usuarios.para_id
        lista_asunto = usuarios.asunto
        lista_fecha = usuarios.fecha


    context = {
        "lista2":lista2,
        "lista_de_id": lista_de_id,
        "lista_para_id": lista_para_id,
        "lista_asunto": lista_asunto,
        "lista_fecha" : lista_fecha


    }
    return render(request, 'app/admin/memolist.html',context)
```

**models.py**

```
class Memorandum(models.Model):
    de = models.ForeignKey(User)
    para = models.ForeignKey(Empleado) 
    fecha = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today)
    detalle = models.TextField()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not replace id with the name. You are using foreign key. So it shows id.

```
for usuarios in lista2:
    lista_de_id = usuarios.de_first_name
    lista_de_first_name = usuarios.de__first_name #user double "_"
    lista_para_id = usuarios.para_id
    lista_asunto = usuarios.asunto
    lista_fecha = usuarios.fecha
```

Comment: I know it shows ID, but I do not want it to be shown by ID, I want the first_name of the User model to take the value in template instead of the id. How do I do it?

Comment: listda_de_id = usuarios.de__first_name should help

Comment: "de" is your user. If you want to use a field of "de" you should put double "_" underscore and write the field name. such as de__first_name, de__username etc

Comment: Just missing {{ usuarios.de.first_name }} in the template. Thanks!